# Preg_match_all from a url

Tags: php

How can i get all the $_GET name => values from a url using preg_match_all

Example url1: http://www.example.com?go1=test1

Example url2: http://www.example.com?go2=test2

Example url3: http://www.example.com?go1=test1&go3=test3

The return need to be via array if is possible

```
$array = array();
$array[name1] = value1;
$array[name2] = value2;
```

...

Comment: Why `preg_match_all`? `$array = $_GET`.

Comment: because the url is not from my website, i get the url from other website and i want to get all the $_GET values from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com?go1=test1&go3=test3';
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $array);
```

This will put the query string parameters in `$array`.

Comment: thank you, this is what i was searching

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to get variables from url, you can also use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get a single Url components like

Using parse_url:

```
$url='http://www.example.com?go1=test1&go3=test3';
var_dump(parse_url($url)['query']);
```

**See Demo** :http://codepad.viper-7.com/AVFDdy

Using preg_match_all:

```
<?php
$re = "/\\?(.*)/"; 
$str = "http://www.example.com?go1=test1"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

**See Regex** :https://regex101.com/r/eB0rQ2/1

Answer (score 0):

try to look $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] option,hopefully it will be helpful.